# Drop columns and order the data by a specific columns' names

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help because I'm not skilled enough to accomplish that task.
I'm going to have several .csv files saved this way (with more and more rows):

```
              ExamTitle              ParametersName ParametersValue
1    Titolo nuovo esame        TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG             446
2    Titolo nuovo esame   TrunkInclination_VPDM_SAG           -0,49
3    Titolo nuovo esame       SagittalImbalance_SAG              -4
4    Titolo nuovo esame   CervicalLordosisDepth_SAG              30
```

And I will export them all within a df with this code.

```
setwd("C:/Users/directory")
tbl_fread <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
  map_df(~fread(.))
```

However, I'd need your help because I want to move the terms in the column ParametersName to "separate columns". I give you my idea about how the df should look.

```
name1<-c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
name2<-c(1:5)
name3<-c(LETTERS[1:5])
name4<-c(letters[6:10])

df<-data.frame(name1, name2, name3,name4)

  name1 name2 name3 name4
1   one     1     A     f
2   two     2     B     g
3 three     3     C     h
4  four     4     D     i
5  five     5     E     j
```

The way I'd like to transform it by names3's values and drop names4 column ->

```
    A   B     C    D    E
1 one two three four five
2   1   2     3    4    5
```

So once I have my df loaded with all the csv, I just pick the columns I need dividing by ParametersName's values.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution with data.table

Since you're using `data.table`, here you can find a full `data.table` solution:

```r
library(data.table)

# get files this way: it is preferable not to use setwd()
files <- list.files(dir, pattern = ".csv$", full.names = TRUE)

# fastest way to read your csv.
# drop here the column you don't want (I assumed it was ExamTitle)
# add id to reshape later
dt <- rbindlist(lapply(files, fread, drop = "ExamTitle"), idcol = "id")

# reshape with `data.table`
dcast(dt, id ~ ParametersName, value.var = "ParametersValue")
#>    id CervicalLordosisDepth_SAG SagittalImbalance_SAG TrunkInclination_VPDM_SAG
#> 1:  1                        30                    -4                     -0,49
#> 2:  2                        30                    -4                     -0,49
#>    TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG
#> 1:                  446
#> 2:                  446
```

### Solution with `tidyverse`

You can also use `tidyverse`. It depends on you and your project.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# read and bind dataframes, add id
map_df(files, read_csv2, .id = "id") %>%

  # remove column
  select(-ExamTitle) %>%

  # reshape
  pivot_wider(names_from = ParametersName, values_from = ParametersValue)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   id    TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG TrunkInclination~ SagittalImbalan~ CervicalLordosi~
#>   <chr>                <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1 1                      446             -0.49               -4               30
#> 2 2                      446             -0.49               -4               30
```

### Solution with Base R

And to conclude, you can also solve your problem with a one-line solution from base R

```r
unstack(Reduce(rbind, lapply(files, read.csv2)), form = ParametersValue ~ ParametersName)
#>  CervicalLordosisDepth_SAG SagittalImbalance_SAG TrunkInclination_VPDM_SAG TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG
#> 1                        30                    -4                     -0.49                  446
#> 2                        16                    -4                     -0.49                  446
```

### Reproducible example

Here, I'll leave a simple reproducible example to run my code.

```r
dir <- tempdir()
write("ExamTitle;ParametersName;ParametersValue
Titolo nuovo esame;TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG;446
Titolo nuovo esame;TrunkInclination_VPDM_SAG;-0,49
Titolo nuovo esame;SagittalImbalance_SAG;-4
Titolo nuovo esame;CervicalLordosisDepth_SAG;30",
          file = file.path(dir, "tmp1.csv"))
write("ExamTitle;ParametersName;ParametersValue
Titolo nuovo esame;TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG;446
Titolo nuovo esame;TrunkInclination_VPDM_SAG;-0,49
Titolo nuovo esame;SagittalImbalance_SAG;-4
Titolo nuovo esame;CervicalLordosisDepth_SAG;30",
          file = file.path(dir, "tmp2.csv"))
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me a lot of solutions!

Comment: no, don't change "id" in that row. There `id` represents the file. If you need ExamTitle as row id when reshaping, first of all don't remove it as I did in the example!!! Then it depends on the solution. For data.table you need to add it in dcast  `id + ExamTitle ~ ParametersName` . For tidyverse it should just work without changing anything, because the function assumes the all the other columns are row ids. Have a try, let me know.

Comment: Sorry mate, I just deleted the question because by using pivot_wider it was already fixed (as you said right now heheh)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
## Loading the required libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

## Creating Dummy Data
df = data.frame(ParametersName = c("TrunkLenght_VPDM_SAG","TrunkInclination_VPDM_SAG","SagittalImbalance_SAG","CervicalLordosisDepth_SAG"),
                ParametersValue = c(445,0.65,-0.87,30))
df1 = df %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = ParametersName, values_from = ParametersValue)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Deepansh - thanks for the answer, but please don't include screenshots of data. Please paste the output directly into the question and format with code fences. Thanks.